# Re-organize Charts in VSTS Queries

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-query

I've created a few charts in a [VSTS Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries) but I can't figure out how to re-organize them.  Is that possible?

---

For example, I want to move 'Task Person Status 2' to the right of 'Task Person Status'.

[image: Charts Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the order of the charts can not be changed. It’s ordered by the chart created date.

So If you want to move Task Person Status 2 to the right of the Task Person Status, you should delete the chart Task Person Status 2 and then create a new chart (method for now).

And I posted an user voice [Enable to change query charts order](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32543767-enable-to-change-query-charts-order) for this feature, you can vote and follow up.